# Jquery - Group and arrange list by data attribute

Tags: jquery, grouping

I am pulling some json data from a Google spreadsheet and using the following to display it:

```
 $(entry).each(function(){
// Column names are section, subcat, heading,description
$('.results ul').prepend('<li data-section="'+this.gsx$section.$t+'" class="'+this.gsx$subcat.$t+'"><span>'+this.gsx$subcat.$t+'</span><h2>'+this.gsx$heading.$t+'</h2><p>'+this.gsx$description.$t+'</p></li>');});
```

The html output is something like this:

  Category1
  ### Access Services
  description goes here
  Category2
  ### Community supports
  description goes here
  Category3
  ### Family responsibility
  description goes here
  Category4
  ### Free resources
  description goes here

What I would like to do is group the li by data attribute - section.

The output would look like this:

```
       <ul>
<li>
  <h1>Section 1</h1>

  <ul>
    <li data-section="Section 1" class="Category1">
      <span>Category1</span>

      <h2>Access Services</h2>

      <p>description goes here</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>

<li>
  <h1>Section 2</h1>

  <ul>
    <li data-section="Section 2" class="Category2">
      <span>Category2</span>

      <h2>Community supports</h2>

      <p>description goes here</p>
    </li>

    <li data-section="Section 2" class="Category3">
      <span>Category3</span>

      <h2>Family responsibility</h2>

      <p>description goes here</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>

<li data-section="Section 3">
  <h1>Section 3</h1>

  <ul>
    <li data-section="Section 3" class="Category4">
      <span>Category4</span>

      <h2>Free resources</h2>

      <p>description goes here</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

[Img of above html output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UyK7b.png)
Most solutions I have found here on Stack are more about 'sorting' not 'grouping and sorting'. Any guidance is appreciated.

I have tried the following but its not quite working:

```
     $('.results li').each(function(){
$('.results li[data-section="'+this.gsx$section.$t+'"]').insertAfter($(this)).wrapAll('<ul />');
```

});

Comment: Loop through your JSON data and build HTML.

Comment: Thanks deepakb. I have updated my question to include what I have tried.

Comment: No you don't have to do the extra loop at the end that you added. In first loop only build the HTML that you want!